# MySql query on two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table 'users' and 'friends' I am having difficulty joining them

```
     users table
    id | name | usercode
    --------------------
    1 | david | 2WM
    2 | Samme | E5N
    3 | Awudu | C0Q
    4 | John  | VX6
    5 | Jerem | FG3

   Friends Table
 id | actor | target
 --------------------
 1  | E5N   | FG3
 2  | 2WM   | VX6
 3  | FG3   | 2WM
 4  | C0Q   | VX6
 5  | FG3   | VX6
```

Basically i want to select all users from USERS table who has 'FG3' in either target or actor column in the FRIENDS table.
The result will be

```
id | name  | usercode | actor | target
--------------------------------------
 2 | Samme | E5N      | E5N   | FG3
 1 | david | 2WM      | FG3   | 2WM
 5 | John  | VX6      | FG3   | VX6
```

I have triend everything i know but still i am not getting the correct results
I will be glad if anyone can help me since I need to present this work tomorrow morning. Thank you

Comment: Did you try a `JOIN`?

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: `join` + `where 'FG3' IN (actor, target)`

Comment: @Hamish yes I have, from inner join to left join and even tried doing subqueries but still. I am not really  good in complex queries like this but the need of it has come

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I have tried a lot so i really don't know which of them will be good enough for you to improve

Comment: @Marc B, please can you elaborate on your answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to join on `usercode` equals `actor` or `target`, then put the 'FG3' part in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.usercode, friends.actor, friends.target
FROM users
INNER JOIN friends
    ON users.usercode = friends.actor OR users.usercode = friends.target
WHERE users.usercode != 'FG3'
AND (friends.actor = 'FG3' OR friends.target = 'FG3');
```

Using `INNER JOIN` limits your query to only records that exist in both tables.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it is returning 6 results instead of three

Comment: @DavidAddoteye Do you want to exclude results for Jerem, since he is FG3? If so, just add `AND users.usercode != 'FG3'` to the end of this query.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have added it and it has remove 2 of the Jerem leaving one. I now have 4 results instead of three. I am wondering why that is left though i have verified the data type and the string

Comment: @DavidAddoteye Possibly order of operations? See how I've arranged the WHERE-AND clause now, with parentheses.